# Phase of reaction between glucose and potassium cyanide to form amygdalin

Tags: organic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, phase, carbohydrates

I'm trying to write a detective-fiction novel, and I was wondering if potassium cyanide reacts with sugar only if the glucose for the amygdalin to form is dissolved in liquid or does it react even if the glucose is still sugar, like sugar cubes?

For example if potassium cyanide was mixed in a sugar canister. Will there be amygdalin or will there be amygdalin only if the potassium and sugar from the canister are mixed in a glass of water?

I can't find the answer in google, and I'm not that good with chemistry.

Answer (score 3):

The glycoside [amygdalin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amygdalin) is a product of enzymatic biosynthesis. Its hydrolysis produces 2 molecules of glucose, benzaldehyde and hydrogen cyanide. Mixing potassium cyanide and sugar ( = sucrose = combined glucose + fructose) does not produce amygdalin. Neither you would get it, mixing glucose, benzaldehyde and hydrogen cyanide.